# Angular Routing cascade redirects (follow 2nd redirect once user has been redirected)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

Have an issue (maybe just for understanding reasons) using angular router.

In short when I call a route which is not allowed yet to being loaded (protected by a guard) I get redirected but if the redirect goes somewhere where a 2nd redirect is configured this one isn't followed

Let's look at the example below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'account',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'account',
        loadChildren: './modules/account/account.module#AccountModule',
        canLoad: [CanLoadAccountGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './modules/dash-board/dash-board.module#DashBoardModule',
        canLoad: [CanLoadDashBoardGuard]
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: ''
    }
];
```

When I'm not authenticated I'm not allowed to access the `/dasboard` route and get immediately redirected to '' (/).

Within the configuration for '' (/) a `redirectTo: 'account'` is configured but but not applied... Browser keeps staying on '' (/).

But if I initially call `/` route the redirect works as expected.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong/missunderstand here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by changing the configuration into the example below.

```
[
    {
        path: 'account',
        loadChildren: './modules/account/account.module#AccountModule'
    },
    {
        path: '',
        canActivateChild: [IsAuthenticatedGuard],

        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'dashboard',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                loadChildren: './modules/dash-board/dash-board.module#DashBoardModule'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: ''
    }
]
```